# Compare every 2 rows and show mismatches in R

Tags: r, dataframe, compare, match, apply

I have searched a lot and tried on my own too, but couldn't find solution for this particular problem.

For every 2 rows ('key' is common), I have to find mismatches in every column and highlight them in an organized way like below.

The output should be in the following format:

```
COLUMN_NAME is not matching for records below:
PRINT COMPLETE RECORDS
...
COLUMN_NAME is not matching for records below:
PRINT COMPLETE RECORDS
...
COLUMN_NAME is not matching for records below:
PRINT COMPLETE RECORDS
...
```

**Input Data** (it's a data frame):

```
key V1  V2  V3  V4  V5
a1  1   2   3   4   5
a1  1   3   9   4   5
a5  2   1   4   7   5
a5  2   1   4   7   6
a6  7   6   8   9   6
a6  7   6   3   9   6
a9  7   6   8   9   4
a9  7   6   8   9   3
```

**Output**:

```
V2 is not matching for records below:
key V1  V2  V3  V4  V5
a1  1   2   3   4   5
a1  1   3   9   4   5


V3 is not matching for records below:
key V1  V2  V3  V4  V5
a1  1   2   3   4   5
a1  1   3   9   4   5
a6  7   6   8   9   6
a6  7   6   3   9   6


V5 is not matching for records below:
key V1  V2  V3  V4  V5
a5  2   1   4   7   5
a5  2   1   4   7   6
a9  7   6   8   9   4
a9  7   6   8   9   3
```

I'm a beginner in R, so please be nice :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first split your data frame by `key`:

```
dfs <- split(df, df$key)  # presuming your data frame is named `df`
```

now write a function taking a data frame and comparing first and second row (for simplicity, we're not going to check whether the data frame actually has 2 rows - that's just taken for granted):

```
chk <- function(x) sapply(x, function(u) u[1]==u[2])
```

and now apply that function to the `split`'ed data:

```
matches <- sapply(dfs,chk)
## so `foo` is a matrix showing, for each variable and each ID, whether there is 
## a match or not
apply(matches, 1, function(x) colnames(matches)[which(!x)])
## and this one takes each row in `foo` and extracts the column name (i.e. key)
## for every TRUE-valued cell.  the result is a list - note that some of the
## elements will be empty
```

The last row outputs the names (`key` column) of the non-matching pairs of each variable.

And now the final step:

```
mm_keys <- apply(matches, 1, function(x) colnames(matches)[which(!x)])
# mm_keys stands for mismatching keys
lapply(mm_keys, function(x) subset(df, key %in% x))
# this one, called `mm_lines` below, takes each element from mm_keys
# .. and extracts (via `subset`) the corresponding lines from the original data frame
```

Ok by this you already have all information that you wanted but not formatted in a nice way. You can do that easily too.

```
mm_lines <- lapply(mm_keys, function(x) subset(df, key %in% x))
mm_lines <- mm_lines[sapply(mm_lines, nrow)>0]  
# leave out variables where there is no mismatch
# for understanding this, try what `sapply(mm_lines, nrow)` does
# and add labels the way you want:
names(mm_lines) <- paste(names(mm_lines), "IS NOT MATCHING FOR RECORDS BELOW:")
```

Now the output:

```
print(boo)
#$`V2 IS NOT MATCHING FOR RECORDS BELOW:`
#  key V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
#1  a1  1  2  3  4  5
#2  a1  1  3  9  4  5
#
#$`V3 IS NOT MATCHING FOR RECORDS BELOW:`
#  key V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
#1  a1  1  2  3  4  5
#2  a1  1  3  9  4  5
#5  a6  7  6  8  9  6
#6  a6  7  6  3  9  6
#
#$`V5 IS NOT MATCHING FOR RECORDS BELOW:`
#  key V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
#3  a5  2  1  4  7  5
#4  a5  2  1  4  7  6
#7  a9  7  6  8  9  4
#8  a9  7  6  8  9  3
```

#### [edit]

Since you asked for it, here is something that does it with on one line and looks a bit more like magick:

```
boo <- (function(x) x[sapply(x, nrow)>0])(lapply(lapply(df, function(x) tapply(x, df$key, function(x) x[1]!=x[2])), function(x) subset(df, key %in% names(which(x)))))
```

And for writing it to a text file ("out.txt") the way you wanted:

```
sink("out.txt")
for(iii in seq_along(boo)){
  cat(names(boo)[iii], "IS NOT MATCHING FOR THE RECORDS BELOW:\n")
  print(boo[[iii]])
  cat("\n")
  }
sink(NULL)
```

Comment: And this is what they call as magic? :)
Brilliant. And thanks a lot for answering.

Would like to request couple of things,
1. Please organize your code for others to understand if they want to
2. And please tell me how to throw the output of boo to a text file or if possible to Excel. XLSX package is converting it to a data frame and messing with the format of the required output.

Comment: Thanks to Akrun, I managed to print the output of boo to a file. But it's sort "Word wrapped" so the columns are entering below. Wish they could appear in one straight line. I have 113 columns to deal with and it's showing 15 columns per line.

Comment: ok you caught me. the first rule of coding is: never use stupid variable names like "blah" and "boo". even if you're going to be the only person to use it - because in, say, 4 months you won't remember what you were thinking today. and a second rule: understandable comments! so I added some comments (that hopefully make it more understandable) and changed the var names. but I couldn't resist and added a piece of real magic too - remove a parenthesis and it won't work. this proves it is real magic. :)

Comment: Brilliant once again :) Thanks!
But one last quirk is that it's sort of word wrapped. Like I mentioned, I deal with 113 columns and it only shows 15 columns per line. Can you do a little bit more magic and show all the columns on one line? Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: see `options()$width`  - it is usually set at something < 100 (max line width when "printing" i.e. showing something on screen. before using the code above, set `options(width=10000)` -- or if your lines are longer than 10000, then the current approach won't work.

Answer (score 0):

You could try `by`

```
res <- c(with(stack(by(df[,-1], df[,1],
         FUN=function(x)names(x)[ x[1,]!=x[2,]])), 
           by(ind, values, FUN=function(x) df[df[,1] %in% x,])))

 names(res) <- paste(names(res), "is not matching for records below")
 res
#$`V2 is not matching for records below`
#  key V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
#1  a1  1  2  3  4  5
#2  a1  1  3  9  4  5

#$`V3 is not matching for records below`
#  key V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
#1  a1  1  2  3  4  5
#2  a1  1  3  9  4  5
#5  a6  7  6  8  9  6
#6  a6  7  6  3  9  6

#$`V5 is not matching for records below`
# key V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
#3  a5  2  1  4  7  5
#4  a5  2  1  4  7  6
#7  a9  7  6  8  9  4
#8  a9  7  6  8  9  3
```

Comment: Since the output is in data frame, it's messing with the format I wanted. Could you please bring it to the format I've written. And thanks for answering :)

Comment: @Pragith Here, the output is in list.  If you want to save the output in a .txt file, you could use `capture.output`. i.e `capture.output(res, file="file1.txt")`  If the output you wanted is a dataframe, it is not clear how you want to place these `labels`

Comment: Akrun, the output isn't accurate as the Best Answer I've picked. Your code is showing mismatch for all the columns. I'm dealing with 113 columns and 10 rows in reality and it's showing mismatches for all.

Comment: @Pragith It is okay.  With the example you showed with multiple columns, it is working.  So, I am not sure wby your original dataset behaves differently.  Do, you have more than 2 records per each key ? Perhaps (10 rows)?