# Compare every n rows and show boolean vector

Tags: r, data.table, compare, rows

I have similar issue like in this questions [Compare every 2 rows and show mismatches in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25679815/compare-every-2-rows-and-show-mismatches-in-r)

I would like to compare not only 2 rows but for example 3, 4, etc.
I have a data.table here:

`DT <- data.table(A = rep(1:2, 2), B = rep(1:4, 2),
                 C = rep(1:2, 1), key = "A")`

Then I use

```
dfs <- split(DT, DT$A)
comp <- function(x) sapply(x, function(u) u[1]==u[2])
matches <- sapply(dfs, comp)
```

For 3 rows :

```
comp <- function(x) sapply(x, function(u) u[1]==u[2] & u[1]==u[3])
```

Is that accurate? How can I generalize it in more elegant way?

Comment: why are you splitting your data by column `A`?

Comment: Besides stas' question, it is not clear what "compare" means here. If you split by A, of course every value of A in each df will be the same, so that row is guaranteed to be TRUE. If you want to check uniqueness per column by A, there's ... `DT[, lapply(.SD, function(x) uniqueN(x) == 1L), by=A]`

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I want to split per A, as an example of some ID per which I need to split data. I want to check uniqueness (or duplicates) per each  column. Though, if all value in B are the same, then TRUE if at least one is different then FALSE.

Comment: I also edited dataset a bit, as when you split per A, there still would be 3 rows to compare.

Comment: Expected output:
`      1     2
A  TRUE  TRUE
B FALSE FALSE
C  TRUE  TRUE`

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
comp2 <- function(dt, i, rws){
      k <- length(rws)
      tmp <- as.numeric(dt[i])
      tmp <- as.data.table(matrix(rep(tmp, k), nrow = k, byrow = TRUE, dimnames = list(NULL, colnames(dt))))
      ans <- (dt[rws] == tmp)
      ans
}
```

this function takes three arguments:
 -> `dt` your `data.table` (or sub-data.tables obtained from splitting your original one, up to you)
 -> `i` -- row you want to compare 
 -> `rws` -- vector of row numbers you want to compare `i` with (e.g. `c(2,3,4)` would compare `i` with rows 2, 3 and 4
it then creates a new `data.table` that consists of row `i` stacked `k` times, so a `data.frame` to `data.frame` comparison is possible.

example:

```
comp2(DT, 1, c(2, 3, 4))
#       A     B     C
#[1,]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
#[2,] FALSE FALSE FALSE
#[3,] FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

compares row 1 of your `data.table` `DT` to rows 2, 3 and 4.

if you want your output to tell you whether your chosen row differs from *at least one* of the rows you are comparing it to, then you need an extra operation `colSums(ans) == k` instead of `ans`.

Comment: Hello, Thank you very much for the answer. If I will have non-numeric values, for example timestamp as column value?

Comment: @Jane any object type that admits `==` as a comparison operator should work with code above. best way to check is to try!